# Probability Unifrom A>B>C

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

For a trading interview assessment I was presented with this problem:

3 traders have a payoff at the end of the day that is uniformly distributed between 0 and 100$.

What is the probability that the Payoff of A is bigger than B and the payoff of B is bigger than C?

---

MY attempt:

The probability of any value in the uniform distribution is $\frac{1}{101}$.

From experience with past problem I think that the probability that A is bigger than B is
$\frac{A+1}{101}$ and B bigger than C is $\frac{B+1}{101}$ which can be written as $\frac{A+1 +1}{101}$

So I thought the correct answer was to multiply those and get $\frac{A^2+3A+2}{101}$

since A should be 1 the probability is $\frac{6}{101}$

Comment: Do not repost a closed question.  **Edit to improve* a closed question.

Comment: Let $X,Y,Z \in A,B,C$. Then evaluate all combinations of $X> Y > Z$. Due symmetry all probabilities of these combinations are the same. And they add up to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Visualize the $1\times 1\times 1$ cube. We want the volume of the region s.t. $z>y>x$. So
$$I=\int_{z>y>x}dzdydx=\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,z]}\int_{[0,y]}dzdydx=\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,z]}ydzdy=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{z^2}{2}dz=\frac{1}{6}$$